# How to find the associated nouns to a preposition

Tags: regex, nltk, spacy, nlp

given a sentence "extinguish the fire in front of the table which is to the right of stool which is to the left of cone then go towards the chair"

we as humans can easily identify the nouns associated with prepositions like

in front of->(fire,table)

to right of ->(table,stool)

towards ->(chair)

we have learnt this through trial and error and practise, but how can I formulate it into some pattern which is applicable globally to all sentences to find the nouns associated , given the prepositions.

So, I would like to know, what pattern (like Verb,preposition,noun etc.) would help me get the nouns associated with the given preposition Thanks.

Comment: Prepositional phrase attachment is a hard problem. It is not generally amenable to solution using regular expressions unless your data is very highly constrained.
Here's a recent paper 
http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~aquattoni/AllMyPapers/iwpt2017.pdf

And here's a search with pointers of lots of papers if you're interested:
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?&q=preposition%20attachment

You may have some luck with using sentence parses. This chapter of the NLTK book talks about the problem a little bit:
http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html

Comment: Well thanks I went forward to do it the hard way. i.e Rule-based approach since the application i'm dealing with has sentences with more or less similar structure.Thanks for the papers though.